# Find common patterns in sequence of words

Tags: python

I have a large list of strings, in which a sequence of sounds is stored. For example:

```
strings = ['A','B','C','G','F','F','F','A',...,'F']
```

What I would like to do is perform a statistical analysis in which I would define the subsequence length and return a list (or a dictionary, which is probably more practical) that goes like this:

```
subsequence_length = 5
output = {['A','B','A','A','F': 129, ['B','G','G','F','F']: 112, ...}

subsequence_length = 3
output = {['A','A','F']: 209, ['G','F','F']: 198, ...}
```

What I have tried so far was creating a sort of kernel that follows a loop, such as:

```
for i in range(0, len(strings) - subsequence_length, subsequence_length):
    # count operation
```

I have struggled, however, with finding a fast solution (when the initial list is very large, like thousands of elements, this method is really not efficient). Is there any regex command (or similar) that can achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: You cannot have lists as keys in dicts - your "expected" dicsts are not even valid python - missing brackets and not valid keys, etc ... please [edit] and condense your question into somthing that you can show with an [mre]

Comment: I've got the answer I needed, thank you Patrick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the natural language processing toolkit `nltk` (install with `pip install nltk`) to achieve your task:

```
output = nltk.FreqDist(nltk.ngrams(strings, subsequence_length))
```

Using `nltk.ngrams` produces sub-sequences of size `subsequence_length`, and then using `nltk.FreqDist` creates a dictionary-like counter object of the sub-sequences.

Comment: You're right, this is a wonderful answer! I was looking into regex and similar functions, while nltk has the perfect tools for the purpose, thank you